# Updating SSRS chart data labels doesn't update all labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple pie chart that is displaying the data labels. When I try and update anything about the data labels the changes are only reflected on one of the data labels. I have observed that this occurs with font, font size, and font color.

Am I changing the style incorrectly? Or how do I go about applying the style to all of the data labels?

I am using SSRS 2008.

**SSRS Design Tab:**

[image: design tab]

**Generated Report:**

[image: design tab]

Edit: I should mention that I can update the heading and legend font without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps to change the font/font size/font color of your data label:

1. In Design Mode, click on the data label you wish to make changes to.
2. Press F4 to display the Properties window. From there you can change the font/font size/font color of your data label.

If this doesn't work, try recreating your pie chart. You may have accidently create conditions on your pie chart so only certain data label changes.

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo8ko.png)

Answer (score 0):

using View Code, You will need to copy and paste the font xml from the working label into the xml section for the other labels.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your chart and change it to something else (I chose bar). Then individually format each series by right clinking on its label, choose Series Label Properties, then click on Number, and then the format you want. Finally, change your chart back to a pie chart.